# Update issue state in close task lost some states . IDEA and JIRA

Tags: intellij-idea, jira

IDEA version: 2018.1

jira veriosn: v6.3.6

In close task, it only show one state, "解决中", it means resolving. But I want to change the state as "已解决"。

I enable categories #com.intellij.tasks  (with hash in the beginning) and httpclient.wire  in Help | Debug Log Settings.

the log is as follows:

```
2018-05-11 11:34:54,140 [ 787590]   INFO - del.JiraTransitionsWrapperApi2 - Unknown required field 'customfield_10100' for transition '已解决'
```

The url request is as follows:

=================== update =======

It works well sometimes,but sometimes it don't work.

1. When it don't work:

1.1 In jira:

The issue status is "解决中", it means resolving.

[image]

1.2 In idea:

update issue state only "打开"，it means open.

[image]

1.3 In idea log:

```
2018-05-11 17:24:35,795 [14543234]  DEBUG - llij.tasks.jira.JiraRepository - URI: http://10.100.1.17:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/JMFX-694/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
2018-05-11 17:24:35,887 [14543326]  DEBUG - llij.tasks.jira.JiraRepository - Status code: 200
2018-05-11 17:24:35,888 [14543327]   INFO - del.JiraTransitionsWrapperApi2 - Unknown required field 'customfield_10100' for transition '已解决'
2018-05-11 17:24:35,888 [14543327]   INFO - del.JiraTransitionsWrapperApi2 - Unknown required field 'customfield_10100' for transition '关闭'
```

1.4 In url:

http://10.100.1.17:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/JMFX-694/transitions?expand=transitions.fields

result:

I save the json to the github repo.

https://github.com/longzl2015/StackOverflow/blob/master/jira1.json

2. when it works well

2.1 In jira:

[image]

2.2 In idea:

[image]

2.3 In idea log:

```
2018-05-11 17:44:04,035 [15711474]  DEBUG - llij.tasks.jira.JiraRepository - URI: http://10.100.1.17:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/JMFX-580/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
2018-05-11 17:44:04,124 [15711563]  DEBUG - llij.tasks.jira.JiraRepository - Status code: 200
2018-05-11 17:45:24,433 [15791872]  DEBUG - llij.tasks.jira.JiraRepository - URI: http://10.100.1.17:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/JMFX-580/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
2018-05-11 17:45:24,522 [15791961]  DEBUG - llij.tasks.jira.JiraRepository - Status code: 200
```

2.4 In url:

http://10.100.1.17:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/JMFX-580/transitions?expand=transitions.fields

result:

I save the json to the github repo.

https://github.com/longzl2015/StackOverflow/blob/master/jira2.json